# Hostname unable to resolve

Tags: dns

**Raspberry Pi 4B Ubuntu 19.10:**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bigbluebutton/support
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Name or service not known

ping: ubuntu: Name or service not know
```

- Why is **unable to resolve host ubuntu: Name or service not known** returned?
- What tests can be performed to determine the root cause of resolution failure?

```
    ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ nslookup ubuntu  
    Server:     8.8.8.8  
    Address:    8.8.8.8#53
```

```
server can't find ubuntu: NXDOMAIN

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dig ubuntu

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1ubuntu2.1-Ubuntu <<>> ubuntu
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 54203
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ubuntu.                IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           51959   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2020011200 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 13 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Jan 13 02:19:00 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 110
```

## UPDATE

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 192.168.8.1
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ nslookup ubuntu
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find ubuntu: NXDOMAIN
```

Comment: Have you modified /etc/hosts ?

Comment: @Millways  I have not.

Comment: `ubuntu` is your local domain name : `ubuntu@ubuntu` = `user@hostname`. If you want to get the ip of ubuntu.com or ubuntu.org or other : `nslookup ubuntu.com` (need `domain.tld`) , because your command get your record for `ubuntu` into /etc/hosts or 8.8.8.8 google dns server can't understand only `ubuntu`

Comment: Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/107232/edit) your question and add the output of this command to it: `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. I'm interested if there is a `search` or `domain` option available.

Answer (score 2):

it seems `add-apt-repository` has a problem to find the right path to the repository that it should add to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Usually it is

```
http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu
```

I don't know how to tell `add-apt-repository` to use this URL because on my default Raspbian installation the command isn't available. You can try to add the repository to `etc/apt/sources.list.d/` manually. For an example look at [How To Add Apt Repository In Ubuntu & Debian](https://tecadmin.net/add-apt-repository-ubuntu/).

Comment: Please comment on what content should be in `/etc/resolv.conf` and why: it would help not just my understanding but the community as well.

Comment: @gatorback I don't know what this `bigbluebutton/support` is and I use Raspbian, not Ubuntu and I do not use a graphical user interface. So I cannot help much with this. It is up to you to find the right repository. I can help you to insert it into the apt sources lists then.